# Use two values in tuple for use as a key in a python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a loop that maps values to a dictionary where the key is a tuple created from a dataframe and the values are floating point numbers. A current example output to looks like:

```
{('A',): 0.776, ('B',): 0.776, ('C',): 0.776, ('D',): 0.776}
```

My goal (and problem) is to pass an additional value to the key, one that specifies the iteration when the key was mapped to a value. My current dictionary expression in the loop is `csv_dict[tuple(cluster)] = sr_mode` but I would like something like `csv_dict[tuple(cluster, k)] = sr_mode`. Expected output would be:

```
{('A',1): 0.776, ('B', 1): 0.776, ('C', 1): 0.776, ('D', 1): 0.776}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Here's the script to reproduce:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

k = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_list = [pd.DataFrame(df[i]) for i in df]
csv_dict = dict()

while k != 1:
    k += 1
    sr_mode = round(random.random(), 3)

    for cluster in df_list:
        csv_dict[tuple(cluster)] = sr_mode

print(csv_dict)
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want extract from `df`

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `k` to be used in the dictionary keys you can simply replace your pre-last two lines by:

```
for cluster in df_list:
    csv_dict[tuple([cluster.columns[0], k])] = sr_mode
```

If you `print(csv_dict)`:

> {('A', 1): 0.62, ('B', 1): 0.62, ('C', 1): 0.62, ('D', 1): 0.62}